# Strange numeric behaviour with paste function

Tags: r, paste

Can anyone explain the strange decimal behavior reproduced below? And how to avoid it? Use rounding I suppose, but I don't see what I should need to.

```
x <- 200.10 
y <- 200.96
paste("Difference", x - y, sep = ":")
# [1] "Difference:-0.860000000000014"
# But not here!
200.10-200.96
# -0.86
```

Comment: ?options and look at the digits parameter.

Comment: instead of using paste, `sprintf("Difference: %.2f", x - y)` will give you `-0.86`, It's a question of how much precision you want to see and use.

Comment: `options(digits=15);  200.10-200.96` will show you ` -0.860000000000014` too.

Comment: I mean, if you want to know the exact reason why it happens.. then you'll have to read the source code of `paste`: https://github.com/wch/r-source/blob/trunk/src/main/paste.c

Comment: Thanks @fishtank. Post as an answer and I will accept.

Comment: @jtdoud posted answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is nothing strange going on. The precision in both case are the same just printed differently.

```
sprintf("Difference: %.2f", x - y) 
# prints -0.86 as in your last output

options(digits=15);  200.10-200.96 
# prints -0.860000000000014 as in your first output
```

The precision in both case is determined by the type (which is `double` in this case). see https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/double.html
and https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/zMachine.html

Answer (score 0):

This happens when dealing with floating point values because of the number of digits used for precision.  You can avoid the problem by ensuring your values have a specific number of decimal places or you may use integers.

Comment: See this post for more info ... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2100490/floating-point-inaccuracy-examples

Comment: there's an important distinction between accuracy and print representation.  They're not quite the same.